# Getting a timed out error in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a google challenge, and I have to solve a puzzle. For this puzzle I have to test if any number touching it on any four sides are equal to one. If so I must change the to the opposite. If one then zero. If zero the one. When I try to run the following code the code lab I'm trying to run it on says the following "Code Timed Out". I checked it,  d it does not seem like the loop should be infinite. No matter what it should eventually return -1 or the number of steps. Can anyone explain this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FooReal {

    public static boolean[] elementsOn = {false, false};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] grid = {{1, 1}, {0, 0,}};
        System.out.println(answer(grid));
    }

    public static int answer(int[][] grid) {
        int steps = 0;

        while (containsOn(grid)) {
            for (int index = 0; index < grid.length; index++) {
                for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < grid[index].length; subIndex++) {
                    if (grid[index][subIndex] == 1) {
                        elementsOn = isElementOn(grid, new int[] {index, subIndex});
                        if (elementsOn[0] || elementsOn[1]) {
                            steps++;
                            for (int counter = 0; counter < grid.length; counter++) {
                                if (grid[counter][subIndex] == 1) {
                                    grid[counter][subIndex] = 0; 
                                } else {
                                    grid[counter][subIndex] = 1;
                                }
                            }

                            for (int counterTwo = 0; counterTwo < grid[index].length; counterTwo++) {
                                if (grid[index][counterTwo] == 1) {
                                    grid[index][counterTwo] = 0;
                                } else {
                                    grid[index][counterTwo] = 1;
                                }
                            }

                            if (grid[index][subIndex] == 1) {
                                grid[index][subIndex] = 0;
                            } else {
                                grid[index][subIndex] = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (steps > 15) {
                    steps = -1;
                    return steps;
                }

            }
        }
        return steps;
    }

    public static boolean[] isElementOn(int[][] grid, int[] elements) {
        boolean[] elementsOn = {false, false};

        //Check if any are on in x row.
        try {
            if (grid[elements[0] + 1][elements[1]] == 1) {
                elementsOn[0] = true;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        try {
            if (grid[elements[0] - 1][elements[1]] == 1) {
                elementsOn[0] = true;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

        //Check if any are on in y row.
        try {
            if (grid[elements[0]][elements[1] + 1] == 1) {
                elementsOn[1] = true;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        try {
            if (grid[elements[0]][elements[1] - 1] == 1) {
                elementsOn[1] = true;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}

        return elementsOn;
    }

    public static boolean containsOn(int[][] grid) {
        for (int index = 0; index < grid.length; index++) {
            for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < grid[index].length; subIndex++) {
                if (grid[index][subIndex] == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: "*I checked it does not seem like the loop should be infinite*" => how did you check? Have you tried debugging your code step by step to see why it does not exit?

Comment: Timed out? are you conecting to a http server, socket, etc?

Comment: It seems your nested loop complexity may be too high and you may want to refactor.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique OP is running on a code lab. It probably limits the running time and other characteristics to avoid DoS.

Comment: As @TheLaw said, you must refactor your code to test atomic piece of code.

Comment: @Thevenin how so? This question is essentially about a long-running, potentially non-terminating algorithm, while the other is about a off-by-one error.

Comment: Unless somebody can explain why the OP should be ignoring ``ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`` I think that's the problem.  When I try to run the code without ignoring these exceptions I see a repeated stream of failed accesses to index -1 and 2.

Comment: I ignore it to get access to the other tests. I know at one point or another I will get an error. But I want to continue to test the other option numAbove numBelow etc...